# How do I modify a started response in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, reverse-proxy

I get InvalidOperationException whenever I try to modify the response and I get the message "...cannot be set because the response has already started". I'm using SharpReverseProxy library so I don't think I could just return a new response. The error gets thrown when setting the status code.

```
        app.UseProxy(new List<ProxyRule> {
            new ProxyRule {
            Matcher = uri => uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/api"),
            Modifier = (uri, req) => {
                var match = Regex.Match(uri.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, "/api.*");
                uri.RequestUri = new Uri($"https://example.com{match.Value}");
                },
                ResponseModifier = async (msg, ctx) =>
                {
                    if (msg.RequestMessage.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
                    {                            
                        //ctx.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    }
                }
            },...
```

Comment: WHY are you trying to modify the response?  It might be easier (and more standard) if you do this with middleware rather than a 3rd party library.  If all you want to do is prevent any POST methods, then just mark your controller methods with [HttpGet] (as you should be doing anyway).

Comment: @Neil It's way more complicated without a library which I started with. The reverse proxy config doesn't seem to work well with controllers since the controller ignored the calls. I'm planning on reading a file from the response (which I also can't seem to figure out) then return 404 if it's a bad file.

Comment: Can you show your controller where the methods marked as GET but accept POST (which is what I think you are trying to do).

Comment: @Neil Get or Post doesn't trigger the 'api' paths: https://pastebin.com/vZQCfgwh

Comment: Can I suggest you create a brand new API project and see what that generates as your code is not 'standard'.  At the top, you don't have a 'controller route', but you do have individual method routes, which is probably the problem.  Change the controller to [Route("/api"], and remove the routes from [HttpGet] and [HttpPost]. I would also recommend  `[ApiController]` on the controller.

Comment: @Neil I have both route and apicontroller at the top of my controller. The routes within the controller work fine, it's the reverse proxy routes that it seems to not recognize.